# How to save image to odoo ir_attachment table using SQL query

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

To improve the speed of this functionality we can use SQL queries instead of Python ORM method. I have lots of products to save `product_template` while adding image to the table am getting an error. After that I recognized the  image saving in `ir_attchment` table. The image saved could not came to the views.

```
product_obj("insert into 
ir_attachment(name,res_name,res_model,res_field,res_id,type) 
values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
[image_medium,name,'product.template','image_medium',res[0],'binary'])
```

Comment: Why do you have to speed up the process?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can't be seen in the view. The binary data isn't saved in the database anymore. That's why your query shortcut won't work.

Some `Binary` fields in Odoo have the parameter `attachment` set to `True` which means, that this field's binary data will be saved into an attachment (`ir.attachment`) with some special configuration. Odoo uses the field `res_field` along with `res_id` and `res_model` to later find such attachments, while loading the data for e.g. form views, as your query is already setting, too.

So my guess is, that Odoo isn't looking into the database for the binary data.

Comment: So i needs to save 10000 of products using query because orm takes more time. This data  are coming through the apis. Is any way to save product image to product_template using qurey?

Comment: Not that i know.